# Problem with subtraction $f(z)=\frac{\mathrm{sh}z}{\left ( z^2+\pi^2 \right )^2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Find all singular points of a given function, determine their nature and find residues in them. Determine what the point at infinity is for a given function and find the residues at it $f(z)=\frac{\mathrm{sh}z}{\left ( z^2+\pi^2 \right )^2}$

The poles are in $z=\pm \pi i$, they are poles of order 2. If $f$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=a$ then $f(z)=k/(z-a)^2+l/(z-a)+g(z)$ where $g$ is analytic and ${\rm res}(f,a)$, by definition, equals $l$.
Hence ${\rm res}(f,a)=\{(z-a)^2 f(z)\}'(a)$

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\mathrm{sh}z}{z+\pi i}\Bigg|_{z=-\pi i}=\frac{(z+\pi i)\mathrm{ch}z-\mathrm{sh}z}{(z+\pi i)^2}\Bigg|_{z=-\pi i}=\frac{i}{2\pi}$$

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\mathrm{sh}z}{z+\pi i}\Bigg|_{z=\pi i}=\lim_{z\to \pi i}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\mathrm{sh}z}{z+\pi i}=0$$

I was able to find the residues for two points, but how to find the residue for infinity?

Comment: What is "shz", anyway? It is perhaps hyperbolic sine? Because I know its widely used symbol is $\;\sinh\;$

Comment: $\mathrm{sh}z=\sinh z$

Comment: This is also a common designation

Comment: I know a result that sum of residues at all singularities and the infinity point is $0$.

Comment: Did I find the residues of two points incorrectly? How did you find the residue at infinity?

Comment: You can find the points $z=\pm\pi i$ are also zero points of $\sinh z$.

Comment: Could you show me how to find the residue at all three points? It is important to understand first of all how to find for infinity

Comment: The points $\;\pm \pi i\;$ are simple poles, as hinted by Cunyi comment. Not order two poles...

Comment: Yes, I know very well about these two points. I need to understand how to calculate the residue at infinity - my question is in the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alternative, which is occasionally more useful. $\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{Res}}$If $f:\hat{\Bbb C}\to\hat{\Bbb C}$ is meromorphic then: $$f(z)=\cdots+a_nz^n+\cdots+a_1z+a_0\color{red}{-\res(f;\infty)z^{-1}}+a_{-2}z^{-2}+\cdots$$For all sufficiently large $z$.

In our context: $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{1}{z^4}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\pi^2/z^2)^2}\cdot\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=\frac{1}{z^4}\cdot\left(\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}(m+1)\pi^{2m}}{z^{2m}}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\end{align}$$For all $z,|z|>\pi$. We want to isolate the $[z^{-1}]$ coefficient which just amounts to finding the $[z^3]$ coefficient of the other series: $$\begin{align}\res(f;\infty)&=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k(k+1)\pi^{2k}}{(3+2k)!}\\&=-\pi^{-1}\sum_{k\ge1}(-1)^k\cdot\frac{k\cdot\pi^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}+\pi^{-3}\sum_{k\ge1}(-1)^k\cdot\frac{\pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\pi^{-1}(\sin(x)/x)'|_{x=\pi}+\pi^{-5}\sin(\pi)-\pi^{-2}\\\\&=-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\end{align}$$If I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $\text{sh}z=\sinh z=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}$, then
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2(z-\pi i)^2(z+\pi i)^2}$$
Since $z=\pm\pi i$ are zeros of $e^{z}-e^{-z}$, in fact the order of poles $z=\pm\pi i$ is one.

And the residue at infinity point can be known from the formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\text{Res}_{z=z_k}+\text{Res}_{z=\infty}=0$$

How to calculate the limit at $z=\pi i$:
$$\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2(z-\pi i)(z+\pi i)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{(z+\pi i)^2+2(z-\pi i)(z+\pi i)}\quad (\text{Using L'Hospital})$$

Comment: Thanks, but what is $\underset{z=z_1,z_2,\ldots}{\mathrm{Res}}$ equal to?

Comment: It is the sum of residue at all $z_k$.

Comment: Did I find the residues at two points correctly? It turns out that their sum is equal to $i/2\pi$, which means the residue at infinity is equal to $-i/2\pi$?

Comment: I calculated the residue at $z=\pm\pi i$ are both $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}$, the sum is $\frac{1}{2\pi^2}$.

Comment: Can you show how you calculated the deductions for these points?

Comment: For example calculate the limit $$\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2(z-\pi i)^2(z+\pi i)^2}\cdot(z-\pi i)$$

Comment: So the answer is $-1/2\pi^2$ for the infinity residue?

Comment: True. You can google for 'residue at infinity'.

Comment: I can't find the limit for $z=-\pi i$, what is it?